# UnauthorizedAccessException when trying to save a photo to the same file a second time

Tags: c#, windows-8

So, the code below allows me to take a picture. I then display the picture. My XAML is bound to the `Photo` property of the `Vehicle` object. It works fine, until I go in and try to take a picture again. I then get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`. I create the file in 'LocalStorage', so I don't believe I need special permissions to write files there. I'm not sure what is causing the error.

```
public async Task TakePicture()
    {
        CameraCaptureUI camera = new CameraCaptureUI();
        camera.PhotoSettings.CroppedAspectRatio = new Size(16, 9);
        StorageFile photo = await camera.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);

        if (photo != null)
        {
            var targetFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            var targetFile = await targetFolder.CreateFileAsync(String.Format
                ("VehiclePhoto{0}.jpg", this.Vehicle.PrimaryKey), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            if (targetFile != null)
            {
                await photo.MoveAndReplaceAsync(targetFile);
                this.Vehicle.Photo = String.Format("ms-appdata:///local/VehiclePhoto{0}.jpg", this.Vehicle.PrimaryKey);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `StoragePhoto` encapsulates some kind of File I/O under the hood. You must properly dispose these objects in order to release the underlying unmanaged OS resources that will keep "hooks" into the file. If you don't dispose them, the application will keep access to the file open, which is probably why your second access to the file gives you an exception (the first access still remains). Show me the StoragePhoto code and I can get more specific.

On another note, if this application is multi-threaded, you should create granular semaphores/locks around writing the files to disk (perhaps by interning the physical path string and locking on that reference) to ensure you don't try to write the same file to disk at the same physical path at the same time - that would be bad.

Comment: Actually, at this point, this is all there is. I have an `Image` that binds to the `Vehicle.Photo` attribute. That vehicle lives in the same class as the above code. After getting it to work, I was going to go through the process of saving the `Vehicle` so that I can call the file later on, but I haven't gotten to that point yet.